# Pandas: mapping list from column values to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a pandas dataframe like below after `prefixspan` algorithim and I want to map those into columns.

```
id  ps_results
...
28  [(301, [1-1]), (63, [1-1, 0-5]), (35, [1-1, 1-...
29  [(265, [0-37]), (31, [1-1, 0-5]), (25, [0-1, 1-1, 0-1...
...
```

For `ps_results` column, there is a very long list of (`frequency`, [`patterns`]), e.g.(63, ['1-1', '0-5']), I want to generate many columns according to this list.

```
[
   (301, ['1-1']),
   (63, ['1-1', '0-5']),
   (35, ['1-1', '1-5']),
   (61, ['1-1', '0-3']),
   (21, ['1-1', '0-3', '1-1']),
   (125, ['1-1', '1-1']),
   (32, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2']),
   (21, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2', '1-1']),
   (46, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1']),
   (20, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
   (50, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
   (27, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1', '1-1']),
   (22, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-5']),
   (26, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-4']),
   (25, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-2'])
   ...
]
```

For example, I want to get some dataframe like below,

`sum_of_freq` = 301 + 63 + 35 + 61 + ... + 25 + ... (for id = 28)

`sum_of_freq` = 265 + 31 + 25 ... (for id = 29)

```
id  ps_results    ['1-1']           ['1-1', '0-5']    ['1-1', '1-5']    ['0-37']  ...rest_of_the_columns
...
28  [(301,[...    301/(sum_of_freq)  63/(sum_of_freq)  35/(sum_of_freq)  0 <--this for other rows
29  [(265, [0...  0                  31/(sum_of_freq)  0                 265/(sum_of_freq)
...
```

Note, the length of `ps_result` for each `id` will vary, there probably have thousands of columns generated at the end.

Below is a small data for experiments.

```
a = {
    'id': ['22', '23'],
    'ps_results': [[(301, ['1-1']), (63, ['1-1', '0-5']), (35, ['1-1', '1-5']),
                    (61, ['1-1', '0-3']), (21, ['1-1', '0-3', '1-1']),
                    (125, ['1-1', '1-1']), (32, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2']),
                    (21, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2', '1-1'])],
                   [(46, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1']),
                    (20, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
                    (50, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
                    (27, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1', '1-1']),
                    (22, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-5']), (26, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-4']),
                    (67, ['1-1', '0-1', '1-1'])]]
}
pd.DataFrame(data=a)
```

Supply table
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want. Let me know if not:

```
a = {
    'id': ['22', '23'],
    'ps_results': [[(301, ['1-1']), (63, ['1-1', '0-5']), (35, ['1-1', '1-5']),
                    (61, ['1-1', '0-3']), (21, ['1-1', '0-3', '1-1']),
                    (125, ['1-1', '1-1']), (32, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2']),
                    (21, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-2', '1-1'])],
                   [(46, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1']),
                    (20, ['1-1', '1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
                    (50, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1']),
                    (27, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-1', '1-1']),
                    (22, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-5']), (26, ['1-1', '1-1', '0-4']),
                    (67, ['1-1', '0-1', '1-1'])]]
}
data = DataFrame(data=a)
data['sum_of_freq'] = data['ps_results'].map(
    lambda tuples: sum(t[0] for t in tuples)
)
exploded = data.explode(column='ps_results')
exploded['freq'] = exploded['ps_results'].map(lambda v: v[0])
exploded['pattern'] = exploded['ps_results'].map(lambda v: v[1])
exploded['freq_ratio'] = exploded['freq'] / exploded['sum_of_freq']
exploded['pattern'] = exploded['pattern'].map(lambda l: tuple(l))
pivot = exploded.pivot(
    index='id', columns='pattern', values='freq_ratio'
).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Not what I want, I want frequency / sum(t[0] for t in tuples) and map each ['1-1', '1-1', '1-2'] in to a column

Comment: Added a table ask me if you not clear

Comment: Oh I didn't look at your table properly. I don't think you can have lists as pandas columns so I turned them into tuples for this.

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace `lambda l: tuple(l)` with `lambda l: str(l)` if you care about the column looking right, but it won't be a list anymore

Comment: How to reset index so I can only have id column and (1-1,),... columns?

Comment: add `.reset_index()` to the last line

Comment: When I apply to more data I got :  `Cell In [3], line 4, in extract_feat_from_pfs.<locals>.<lambda>(tuples)
      1 def extract_feat_from_pfs(data:pd.DataFrame):
      3     data['sum_of_freq'] = data['ps_results'].map(
----> 4         lambda tuples: sum(t[0] for t in tuples)
      5     )
      6     exploded = data.explode(column='ps_results')
      7     exploded['freq'] = exploded['ps_results'].map(lambda v: v[0])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: I found it is list in the example, but the string in real data, I will change the type...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249412/discussion-between-yiffany-and-vahndi).